# C++ Trouble inserting new node into middle of linked list

Tags: c++

I have been stuck for several days on this. I am trying to insert a node into a linked list. I am able to insert the node into start of an empty list and at the beginning of a list, but I am running into trouble with middle & end insertion. Any help would be appreciated & thank you in advance! 8)

I am currently getting the following error message, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
$ g++ a1.cpp
a1.cpp: In function ‘int allocate_memory(int, int)’:
a1.cpp:165:46: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
if (t->next != NULL && p->start_byte < t->next) // inserting p into middle of alloclist
                                          ^
```

My program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct FREE_NODE * FREEPTR;
typedef struct ALLOCNODE * ALLOCPTR;

struct FREE_NODE    // FREE LIST NODES
{
    int start_byte;
    int end_byte;
    int size;

    FREEPTR next;
};

struct ALLOCNODE    // ALLOCATED LIST NODES
{
    int start_byte;
    int end_byte;
    int size;
    int id;

    ALLOCPTR next;
};

FREEPTR freelist = NULL;    // the FREE link list
ALLOCPTR alloclist = NULL;  // the ALLOCATED link list
int total_memory_managed = 0;   // the amount of memory managed

void init_memory_manager(const int amount)
{
    total_memory_managed = amount;

    freelist = new FREE_NODE;   // set up the freelist linked list
    freelist -> size = amount;
    freelist -> start_byte = 0;
    freelist -> end_byte = amount - 1;
    freelist -> next = NULL;

    alloclist = NULL;   // set up the alloclist linked list
}

//--------------------
int largest_free(void)
{
    FREEPTR temp = freelist;    //temp pointer to freelist
    int largest_free = 0;   //initialize largest_free

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->size > largest_free)  //compares size field & remembers largest as it cycles through freelist
        largest_free = temp->size;
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    }
    return largest_free;    //return largest free node available
}

//--------------------
int allocate_memory(const int job, const int amount)
{
    if (amount <=0 || amount > total_memory_managed || amount > largest_free()) //Excludes special cases
    return 0;

    FREEPTR temp = freelist;    // temp pointer points to freelist 
    int num = 0;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->size < amount)
            temp->next;
        else
        {   num = temp->end_byte;
            temp->size = temp->size - amount;
            temp->end_byte = temp->end_byte - amount;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (num == 0)
       return -99;

    ALLOCPTR p = new ALLOCNODE;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->end_byte = num;
    p->size = amount;
    p->start_byte = num - amount +1;
    p->id = job;

    ALLOCPTR t = alloclist;

    if (alloclist == NULL)  // inserting p into empty alloclist
    alloclist = p;
    else
        if (p->start_byte < alloclist->start_byte)  //inserting p into beginning of alloclist
         {
            p->next = alloclist;
            alloclist = p;                  
         }   
        else
             if (t->next != NULL && p->start_byte < t->next) // inserting p into middle of alloclist
             {
                 p->next = t->next;
                 t->next = p;
             }
             else
             {
                 while (t->next != NULL) // inserting p at end of alloclist
                 {
                     t = t->next;
                 }
                 t->next = p;                
             }

//insert function to remove zero size nodes

// return amount of memory allocated
}

// MAIN ===================================================================

int main(void)
{
    init_memory_manager(256);
    allocate_memory(1,20);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is waaaay to long to analyze in-depth, but guessing by the line you provided, you probably just need to convert `t->next` to an int before comparing.

```
reinterpret_cast<int>(t->next);
```

If you want more detail - please provide code that's as short as it can be and reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question. I have reduced the program to the bare essentials. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure where to put it in the code. I inserted it above the //Inserting p into middle of alloclist comment, and I got the error code = error: cast from ‘ALLOCPTR {aka ALLOCNODE*}’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
   reinterpret_cast<int>(t->next);

Comment: Well, you should insert it inside the `if`: `if (t->next != NULL && p->start_byte < reinterpret_cast<int>(t->next))`. The error you get is because `sizeof(t->next) > sizeof(int)`. Try changin `start_byte` and `end_byte` to pointers, since you want them to point at some place in the memory anyhow (`char* start_byte` and `char* end_byte`).

Comment: Also - please note - comparing addresses like that is unreliable. There's no real reason to do that.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find a way to simplify the if statement so that there isn't so much going on. Thanks for your insights!